# How to read processing instruction from an XML file using .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, processing-instruction

How to check whether an Xml file have processing Instruction

Example

```
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Sample.xsl"?>

 <Root>
    <Child/>
 </Root>
```

I need to read the processing instruction

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Sample.xsl"?>
```

from the XML file.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: there's no such thing as "C# 3.5". You are asking about .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about:

```
XmlProcessingInstruction instruction = doc.SelectSingleNode("processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')") as XmlProcessingInstruction;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `FirstChild` property of `XmlDocument` class and `XmlProcessingInstruction` class:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("example.xml");

if (doc.FirstChild is XmlProcessingInstruction)
{
    XmlProcessingInstruction processInfo = (XmlProcessingInstruction) doc.FirstChild;
    Console.WriteLine(processInfo.Data);
    Console.WriteLine(processInfo.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(processInfo.Target);
    Console.WriteLine(processInfo.Value);
}
```

Parse `Value` or `Data` properties to get appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

How about letting the compiler do more of the work for you:

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);

XmlProcessingInstruction StyleReference = 
    Doc.OfType<XmlProcessingInstruction>().Where(x => x.Name == "xml-stylesheet").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your answer to explain how does the code in this answer work.