# How to read a processing instruction from XML string using C# .NET?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I would like to read a [processing instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction) from some small [well-formed XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document) chunk, based on this post: [How to read processing instruction from an XML file using .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100345/how-to-read-processing-instruction-from-an-xml-file-using-net-3-5)

However, it doesn't work. I get the error, that the pi object is null.
This is what I do:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root>Text <?pi 1?>blabla</root>");
Console.WriteLine(doc.ChildNodes[0].Name); // output: root

XmlProcessingInstruction pi = doc.OfType<XmlProcessingInstruction>().Where(x => x.Name == "pi").FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(pi.Value);
```

Parsing the XML works. When I get the error (System-NullReferenceException) in Visual Studio, I get it for line "Console.WriteLine(pi.Value);".

Where the error? How do I get/read the processing instruction?

Comment: this does not look like a valid xml.

Comment: it is well-formed XML. Does it have to be valid in order to access the PIs? When I inspect the XmlDocument object, it shows a successful parse tree.

Comment: it is not a valid XML or at least it is not a valid processing instruction. try `doc.LoadXml("<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"Sample.xsl\"?><Root><Child/></Root>")`

Comment: There is a difference between "valid XML" and "well-formed XML". Please cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document for an explanation. The code above uses well-formed XML. It's not wrong. I also tried to change the code and add the <?xml...> tag at the beginning and a child element (just to be sure), but no change. Your example code also doesn't contain a processing instruction (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues in your code.

The first is that it fails on `Console.WriteLine(doc.ChildNodes[1].Name);`, "root" is the first node, not the second (zero-based). But this is probably a typo.

As to the issue in question:

[Enumerable.OfType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-3.5) is using GetEnumerator() of `XmlDocument` class which is implemented by it's parent [XmlNode.GetEnumerator()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.getenumerator?view=netframework-3.5). The documentation states:

> An IEnumerator object that can be used to iterate through the child nodes in the current node.

But you are trying to run OfType on **doc**, who has only a single child: **root**.

If you change your code to run on root's children instead, it will work as expected:

```
XmlProcessingInstruction pi = doc.ChildNodes[0].OfType<XmlProcessingInstruction>().Where(x => x.Name == "pi").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Also, may I suggest a debugging strategy, the one I used to find your issue:  
In your case, it would appear that `pi` being null is the problem. But this is only because of `FirstOrDefault()` which will return null in case it has no first.   
If you break down the expression into seperate variables and inspect each step, you will find that `doc.OfType<XmlProcessingInstruction>()` returns an empty enumerable. Every time I see a Linq expression that doesn't do what I want, I first break it apart to make sure I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the index was a typo. And I like the debug strategy.

Answer (score 0):

With XmlDocument:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.xml");

// get all instructions
var instructions = doc.SelectNodes("//processing-instruction()");

foreach (XmlProcessingInstruction instruction in instructions)
    Console.WriteLine(instruction.Target + " : " + instruction.Data);

// get concrete instruction
var pi = doc.SelectSingleNode("//processing-instruction('pi')") as XmlProcessingInstruction;
Console.WriteLine(pi.Target + " : " + pi.Data);
```

LINQ to XML. It's much more convenient and easier:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var instructions = xml.DescendantNodes()
    .OfType<XProcessingInstruction>();

foreach (var instruction in instructions)
    Console.WriteLine(instruction);

var pi = instructions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Target == "pi");
Console.WriteLine(pi.Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work this way:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("c:\\test\\xmlData.xml");
             
   List<XmlProcessingInstruction> piList = new List<XmlProcessingInstruction>(); 
      foreach (XmlNode cnode in doc.ChildNodes)
       {
         foreach (var ccnode in cnode)
         {
           if (ccnode is XmlProcessingInstruction)
               piList.Add(ccnode as XmlProcessingInstruction);
         }
      }
      Console.WriteLine(piList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "pi").Value);
   }
```

xmlData.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <root>
     <?pi 1?>
       <value>6</value>
     </root>
```

I believe the reason you couldn't get pi was that you didn't have quotes around your Pi target and value. I could not get it to work as a string, but it worked fine reading from a file.

Answer (score -3):

```
{
    private float _length;
    private int _toeCount;


    public Socks()
    { //code here;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Socks arg)) return false;

        return (this._length.Equals(arg._length));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public static int SortByWidthToe(Socks a, Socks b)
    {
        if (a == null && b == null) return 0;
        if (a == null) return -1;
        if (b == null) return 1;

        if (a._length.Equals(b._length))
            return a._toeCount.CompareTo(b._toeCount);

        return a._length.CompareTo(b._length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surrounding your code with some explanation would seriously improve your answer.